# Set text of datatemplate?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

sorry, I am pretty new in WPF and I think it's pretty easy, but I have no idea right now.

I have a DataTemplate which I want to use as a TreeViewItem-Header (I've copied the template from somewhere else, so I am not really sure what it does at the TextBlock part):

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="WI_Bug">
        <DockPanel>
            <Image Source="images\bug-icon.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>
            <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Now I create a new item in C# code:

```
TreeViewItem tvi = new TreeViewItem();
tvi.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate) this.Resources["WI_Bug"];
tvi.Header = "I am a bug";
treeView1.Items.Add(tvi);
```

My problem: The icon, that I've set in the datatemplate is shown, but the header text itself doesn't appear anymore. **How can I fill the TextBlock from the DataTemplate in the C#-code?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataContext` in the `HeaderTemplate` is the `Header`, the `Header` is a string, it has no `Name` property (where is that supposed to be anyway?).

If you just have a string you want a binding directly to the `DataContext`: `{Binding}`

You also might want to read up on [debugging data bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx), it helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this. and you should check your output window for binding errors, because that happens with your example

```
<Window.Resources>
 <DataTemplate x:Key="WI_Bug">
    <DockPanel>
        <Image Source="images\bug-icon.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>
        <TextBlock Text ="{Binding Path=.}"/>
    </DockPanel>
 </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```